# gradient overlay

Tags: css

I need to give background gradient+overlay to the body tag. The gradient+overlay image will look like as attached.

[image]

The problem is I want this to nicely repeat all through the page. if I take this and put in the background and say repeat, then gradient overlay doesnt work.Bsically I want the gradient color to smoothly flow all through the page and also the overlay to be there over the background . Any idea how to do similar with css/css3?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - have a look at that. You won't be able to do the diagonal lines though. You may have to put them over the top in another element.

Comment: Could you please show your current CSS code?

Comment: @boz No, you can do the diagonal lines with a linear gradient, too. And you don't have to use another element, because CSS3 supports multiple backgrounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is the best CSS gradient tool/generator in my opinion

EDIT
This supports radial and diagonal linear gradients